# Can't manage to get nginx working - 301 Moved Permanently #newbie

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is a fresh server running on Ubuntu 20.04 and I never managed to get a webpage displayed. I am a real newbie so the question may be silly. I did look other the existing topics but couldn't manage to sort out my issue. Let me know if something else is needed.

$sudo service nginx status

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-12-11 22:02:51 CET; 11min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 3534 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3535 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3551 (nginx)
      Tasks: 28 (limit: 19660)
     Memory: 411.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─3536 Passenger watchdog
             ├─3539 Passenger core
             ├─3551 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─3559 nginx: worker process
             ├─3560 nginx: worker process
             ├─3561 nginx: worker process
             └─3683 Passenger RubyApp: /home/decidim/decidim-app (production)
```

$curl -i http://127.0.0.1/nginx_status

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://127.0.0.1/nginx_status
Date: Sat, 11 Dec 2021 21:14:20 GMT
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.12
Server: nginx/1.18.0 + Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.12
```

$sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:33:06 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:41:38 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:44:28 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:47:46 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:47:46 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:48:09 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:49:12 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:21:54:17 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:22:05:13 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "Lynx/2.9.0dev.5 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/3.6.13"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2021:22:14:20 +0100] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"

==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:50.9510 3497/Tf Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:50.9510 3497/Tf Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:50.9510 3497/T7 Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:50.9510 3497/T7 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:51.0300 3536/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:51.0563 3539/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:51.0564 3539/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:51.0665 3539/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 3539
[ N 2021-12-11 22:02:53.2192 3539/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 3569 output: DeprecatedDSL will be removed from GraphQL-Ruby 2.0, use `.to_non_null_type` instead of `!` and remove `.activate` from /home/decidim/.rben
v/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/decidim-core-0.25.2/lib/decidim/core/engine.rb:89:in `block in <class:Engine>'
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
## See sample authentication script at:
## http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
## auth_http localhost/auth.php;
## pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
## imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#server {
#listen     localhost:110;
#protocol   pop3;
#proxy      on;
#}
# 
#server {
#listen     localhost:143;
#protocol   imap;
#proxy      on;
#}
#}
```

$ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

```
decidim.conf
```

$more /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/decidim.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name the_real_ip_adress_I_want_to_hide;
    client_max_body_size 32M;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/decidim/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/decidim/decidim-app/public;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in curl report, the redirect to https protocol is initiated by the Phusion Passenger.
Then nginx can't handle the request because there are no servers that listen to port 443.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aleksey. How can I change that?

Comment: You should add listen 443 directive to your server block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/decidim.conf and configure https. See manual  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks. I managed to work around the problem.